# egrep from Java fails while in shell succeed

Tags: java, shell

I run egrep using Java Runtime.exec()

```
String command = "egrep \'(Success|Loading\\.\\.\\.|Loaded : READY|Found a running instance)\' "+ instance.getPath() + "/log";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

The stdout is always null and stderr shows "egrep: Unmatched ( or (". but when I copy the command to shell and run, it returns the correct value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple: `(Success|Loading\\.\\.\\.|Loaded` is not a valid regex.

You can't protect white space with quotes when using `Process.exec(String)`. Always use the versions of `exec()` that take an array or, even better, use `ProcessBuilder`.

That way, you can pass each argument as a single Java String and spaces and other special characters won't create any problems.

Answer (score 0):

The single quotes should not be escaped.  You don't escape them on the command line, either, do you?